# Como usar un array que recibes por un request en un whereIn

Tags: jquery, laravel, ajax

Tengo una funcion que le paso un array de brands y luego se lo paso al whereIn y lo retorno como respuesta a una peticion ajax, pero me salta siempre un error

```
public function filterProduct(Request $request)
{
  $products = Product::whereIn('manufacturer_id', $request->brands)->get();

  return response($products);
}
```

Metodo ajax que llama a la funcion

```
            $('.checkboxAttributes').on('click',function(){
            var $brands = [];//Array vacio donde guardare todos los id de las marcas seleccionadas
            var $attributes = [];//Array vacio donde guardare todos los id de los atributos seleccionadas

            //Iteracion que almacena todas las marcas seleccionadas en un array 
            $('.checkboxBrands:checked').each(function(){
                $brands.push(this.value);
            });

            //Iteracion que almacena todos los atributos seleccionadas en un array 
            $('.checkboxAttributes:checked').each(function(){
                $attributes.push(this.value);
            });

            $.ajax({
                type : 'get',
                url : '{{URL::to('filterProduct')}}',
                data:{'brands':JSON.stringify($brands), 'attributes':JSON.stringify($attributes)},
                headers: { 'csrftoken' : '{{ csrf_token() }}' },
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
```

Me sale este error en la consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿y cual es el error?

Comment: Ya he subido una imagen con el error que me muestra la consola

Comment: No veo en tu código el `foreach()` al que hace referencia de la linea `765`

Comment: No tengo ningun foreach(), me imagino que el metodo whereIn internamente funcionara con algun foreach(), eso ya es asunto de eloquent

Comment: Al principio de `filterProduct()` hacé un  `dd($request->brands)` para ver exactamente que contiene. Fijate lo que devuelve la consola y actualizá tu pregunta. Es probable que sea un `JSON` y necesites hacer un `$brands = json_decode($request->brands)`.

Answer (score 1):

He trabajado con esto y siempre paso un array simple.

Creo que en cuanto a estructura de código está correcta la consulta, pero me da que el `$request->brands`

No es un tipo de dato correcto interpretable por un "wherein".

---

Existen 3 formas de realizar un whereIn y la razón es dependiendo de la precisión o tipo de dato a filtrar:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-wherein

```
El método whereIn filtra la colección por una clave / valor dado 
contenido dentro del array dado
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-whereinstrict

```
Este método tiene la misma forma que el método whereIn; sin embargo, 
todos los valores se comparan usando comparaciones "estrictas".
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-whereinstanceof

```
El método whereInstanceOf filtra la colección por un tipo de clase dado
```

---

Adicionalmente, si ese dato del Request, lo puedes obtener de una consulta, quizás puedas considerar el uso de"subquery":

```
Products::whereIn('manufacturer_id', function($brandsQuery){
    $brandsQuery->select('my_column')
    ->from(with(new ProductCategory)->getTable())
    ->whereIn('category_id', ['n1', 'n2'])
    ->where('active', false);
})->get();
```

Espero que sea de ayuda

Saludos!